# Complexity of Double-Horn-SAT?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability, complexity-classes

On one hand, [Horn-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability) is known to be tractable in linear time - where Horn-SAT is the problem of deciding whether a given set of propositional Horn clauses (with at most one positive literal) is satisfiable or not.
On the other hand, Double-SAT is NP-complete (see this post : [Proving Double-SAT is NP-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6371/proving-double-sat-is-np-complete)) - where Double-SAT is the problem of deciding whether a given set of propositionnal clauses has at least two models.

Let Double-Horn-SAT be the problem of deciding whether a given set of propositional Horn clauses has at least two models.

What is the complexity of Double-Horn-SAT ?

Comment: Perhaps this is a polynomial time solution: given a set $X$ of Horn clauses, find the first solution $S_1$, then for each variable $x_i$ repeat the following procedure: augment the set $X$ with the clause $C_{n+1} = \lnot x_i$ if $x_i=true \in S_1$, or $C_{n+1} = x_i$ if $x_i=false \in S_1$ and check if the augmented set has a solution $S_2$ (which is also a valid second solution for the original set $X$). If no solutions are found for the augmented sets, then the original $X$ doesn't have a second solution.

Comment: Why? (a Horn clause is a clause with at most one positive literal ... but perhaps I'm missing something trivial ) $X \cup x_1$, $X \cup \lnot x_1$ are both valid sets of Horn clauses

Comment: Oups my mistake - let me check.

Comment: I dont see why if no solutions are found for the augmented set, then the original $X$ doesn't have a second solution - because your augmented set is much more restrictive (it doesn't forbid only $S_1$.)

Comment: Suppose that in the first solution $x_1 = false$, then the augmented set $X \cup x_1$ forbids all $x_1=false$ solutions ... but the second model *must* differ from the first solution in at least one variable; so checking  the $n$ sets (the Horn-SAT algorithm is run n times): $X \cup (\lnot)x_1$, $X \cup (\lnot)x_2$, ..., $X \cup (\lnot)x_n$ should (I'm still thinking about it) to a valid second solution (different from the first one) if and only if it exists.

Comment: I see : you augment the set by only one clause, which is different at each step... It seems to work...

Comment: The result is also proved in the dicothomy theorem by Laurent Juban:  Dichotomy Theorem for the Generalized Unique Satisability Problem (I don't have access to the paper, but found [this post on cstheory](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3575/complexity-of-finding-a-second-solution-given-a-correct-solution-to-an-np-comple) ). Can I convert it into an answer?

Comment: Please do, I will accept it - tks for the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Double-Horn-SAT is polynomial-time solvable.

Given a set of Horn-clauses $X = \{C_1,C_2,...,C_n\}$ and a solution $x_1=b_1,x_2=b_2,...,x_n=b_n$, $b_i \in \{true,false\}$ we can observe that a second solution *must* differ in at least one variable $x_i$.
So we can run the Horn-SAT algorithm $n$ times on the augmented set $X_i' = X \cup \{ \lnot x_i \}$ if in the first solution $x_i = true$ or on the augmented set $X_i' = X \cup \{ x_i \}$ if in the first solution $x_i = false$. If we find  a solution for one of the $X_i'$ then it is a valid solution for the original set $X$, too and by construction it differs from the first one; otherwise the original set doesn't have a second solution, as can be easily proved by contradiction.

See also the question "[Complexity of finding a second solution given a correct solution to an NP-complete problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3575/complexity-of-finding-a-second-solution-given-a-correct-solution-to-an-np-comple)" on cstheory and Laurent Juban, [Dichotomy theorem for the generalized unique satisfiability problem](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-48321-7_27) (1999)