# I need to show that the problem is NP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, satisfiability, 3-sat

Double-SAT = {:  has at least two satisfying truth assignments}. Hint: reduce from SAT. Start with a formula  and modify it to get a formula  so that  is satisfibale if and only if  has at least two satisfying truth assignments. If  is not satisfiable, then  also needs to be unsatisfiable.

How do I  the problem lies in NP, and  show that some NPcomplete problem reduces to it

Comment: Just add a dummy variable $x$. If you require that all variable must appear in at least one clause, then add a dummy clause $(x \vee \overline{x})$ too.

Comment: @Steven That should be an answer!

Comment: Please credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Has been asked before on this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving DOUBLE-SAT is NP-complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6371/proving-double-sat-is-np-complete)